# Problems with software installation after kernel update

Tags: 13.04, updates, kernel, update-manager, software-sources

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit.
I decided to install Linux kernel 3.10 which was released recently so, i downloaded the kernel and header packages from `kernel.ubuntu.com` since it's not in raring repositories. I was able to install Headers without problems but when i tried to install the kernel, i got this error

```
root@pulkit-Vostro-1014:/home/pulkit/Downloads# dpkg -i kernel.deb
(Reading database ... 222087 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace linux-image-3.10.0-031000-generic 3.10.0-031000.201306301935         (using kernel.deb) ...
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at   /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing kernel.deb (--install):
subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.10.0-031000-generic   /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-031000-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-extlinux 3.10.0-031000-generic   /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-031000-generic
P: Checking for EXTLINUX directory... found.
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.9.7-030907-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-25-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-031000-generic...
P: Writing config for Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1...
P: Installing debian theme...cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/share/syslinux/themes/debian-   wheezy/extlinux/memtest.bin’: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-extlinux exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm line 328.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
kernel.deb
```

Also, whenever I try to install/remove any software I get this:

```
root@pulkit-Vostro-1014:/home/pulkit/Downloads# sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-image-3.10.0-031000-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't     find an archive for it.
```

Please help me out!

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.10.0-031000-generic`. If that does not work try `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Answer (score 0):

```
P: Installing debian theme...cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/share/syslinux/themes/debian-wheezy/extlinux/memtest.bin’: No such file or directory
```

I countered this with the bold:

```
touch /usr/share/syslinux/themes/debian-wheezy/extlinux/memtest.bin
```

Use at your own risk, but it worked for me.

ps: I didn't try booting into memtest